# PostgreSQL UPDATE equivalent for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a simple MySQL query that I want to convert to PostgreSQL. After 3 days I finally quit as I don't understand what wrong here:

```
UPDATE webUsers u, 
(SELECT IFNULL(count(s.id),0) AS id, p.associatedUserId FROM pool_worker p 
LEFT JOIN shares s ON p.username=s.username 
WHERE s.our_result='Y' GROUP BY p.associatedUserId) a
SET shares_this_round = a.id WHERE u.id = a.associatedUserId
```

I have tried to convert it but it says error on SET. Here is my query:

```
UPDATE webusers 
SET (shares_this_round) = (a.id)
FROM (SELECT coalesce(count(s.id),0) AS id, p.associatedUserId FROM pool_worker p 
LEFT JOIN shares s ON p.username=s.username WHERE s.our_result='Y' GROUP BY p.associatedUserId) a, webusers w WHERE u.id = a.associatedUserId
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with it? I can't sleep just because of this.

```
     ------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------
```

shares table

```
CREATE TABLE shares (
id bigint NOT NULL,
rem_host character varying(255) NOT NULL,
username character varying(120) NOT NULL,
our_result character(255) NOT NULL,
upstream_result character(255),
reason character varying(50),
solution character varying(1000) NOT NULL,
"time" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

webusers table

```
CREATE TABLE webusers (
id integer NOT NULL,
admin integer NOT NULL,
username character varying(40) NOT NULL,
pass character varying(255) NOT NULL,
email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
"emailAuthPin" character varying(10) NOT NULL,
secret character varying(10) NOT NULL,
"loggedIp" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
"sessionTimeoutStamp" integer NOT NULL,
"accountLocked" integer NOT NULL,
"accountFailedAttempts" integer NOT NULL,
pin character varying(255) NOT NULL,
share_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
stale_share_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
shares_this_round integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
api_key character varying(255),
"activeEmail" integer,
donate_percent character varying(11) DEFAULT '1'::character varying,
btc_lock character(255) DEFAULT '0'::bpchar NOT NULL
);
```

pool_workes table

```
CREATE TABLE pool_worker (
id integer NOT NULL,
"associatedUserId" integer NOT NULL,
username character(50),
password character(255),
allowed_hosts text
);
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Oh really sorry i have updated the question

Comment: +1 thanks for following up and updating.

Comment: @CraigRinger - np, its just that i am all into this problem and working on a bitcoin front end so don't get much time to even breath

Comment: With added table definitions, this is a good question now. Next time, remember to include program versions, too. Relevant most of the time.

Comment: Ya i do just i was about to faint so couldn't think to much clearly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I formatted to arrive at this less confusing but still **incorrect** query:

```
UPDATE webusers 
SET   (shares_this_round) = (a.id)
FROM  (
   SELECT coalesce(count(s.id),0) AS id, p.associatedUserId
   FROM   pool_worker p 
   LEFT   JOIN shares s ON p.username=s.username
   WHERE  s.our_result='Y'
   GROUP  BY p.associatedUserId) a
   , webusers w
WHERE u.id = a.associatedUserId
```

There are multiple distinct errors and more sub-optimal parts in this statement. Errors come first and with  **bold** emphasis. The last few items are just recommendations.

1. **Missing alias** `u` for webuser. A trivial mistake.
2. **Missing join** between `w` and `a`. Results in a cross join, which hardly makes any sense and is a very expensive mistake as far as performance is concerned. It is also completely uncalled for, you can drop the **redundant second instance of `webuser`** from the query.
3. `SET   (shares_this_round) = (a.id)` is a **syntax error**. You cannot wrap a column name in the `SET` clause in parenthesis. It would be pointless anyway, just like the parenthesis around `a.id`. The latter isn't a syntax error, though.
4. As it turns out after comments and question update, you created the table with **double-quoted `"CamelCase"` identifiers** (which I advise not to use, ever, for exactly the kind of problems we just ran into). Read the chapter [Identifiers and Key Words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the manual to understand what went wrong. In short: non-standard identifiers (with upper-case letters or reserved words, ..) have to be double-quoted at all times.
   I amended the query below to fit the new information.
5. The aggregate function `count()` never returns `NULL` by definition. `COALESCE` is pointless in this context. I quote [the manual on aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html):

   > It should be noted that **except for count**, these functions return a
   >   null value when no rows are selected.

   Emphasis mine. The count itself works, because `NULL` values are not counted, so you actually get 0 where no `s.id` is found.
6. I also use a different column alias (`id_ct`), because `id` for the count is just misleading.
7. `WHERE s.our_result = 'Y'` ... if `our_result` is of type `boolean`, like it seems it should be, you can simplify to just `WHERE s.our_result`. I am guessing here, because you did not provide the necessary table definition.
8. It is almost always a good idea to avoid UPDATEs that do not actually change anything (rare exceptions apply). I added a second `WHERE` clause to eliminate those:

   ```
   AND   w.shares_this_round IS DISTINCT FROM a.id
   ```

   If `shares_this_round` is defined `NOT NULL`, you can use `<>` instead because `id_ct` cannot be `NULL`. (Again, missing info in question.)
9. `USING(username)` is just a notational shortcut that can be used here.

Put everything together to arrive at this **correct** form:

```
UPDATE webusers w
SET    shares_this_round = a.id_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT p."associatedUserId", count(s.id) AS id_ct
   FROM   pool_worker p 
   LEFT   JOIN shares s USING (username)
   WHERE  s.our_result = 'Y'                        -- boolean?
   GROUP  BY p."associatedUserId"
   ) a
WHERE w.id = a."associatedUserId"
AND   w.shares_this_round IS DISTINCT FROM a.id_ct  -- avoid empty updates
```

Comment: You're willing to spend WAY more time than I am on questions where the OP didn't bother to post error messages, schema, etc. I'm sure it's helping you improve your psychic diagnostic powers :-) and you're a more patient man than me.

Comment: @CraigRinger: *Psychic* is a nice cue. :) All the missing basic information makes it seem like people do believe in psychics sometimes. But let me quote [The Mentalist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o-gj04UUSU): "There is no such thing as a psychic." In this particular case it may have been a bit rash to diagnose it as "syntactically valid", considering the multiple syntax errors.

Comment: The parser is more staged than I realised. It'll bomb out very early if the table to be updated doesn't exist, and won't bother to parse the rest of the query - to get to the bits that aren't actually parseable. Creating the tables confirms that's the case. As for psychic; I'm using it in the sense of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/ - "psychic debugging" referring to debugging with insufficient information using experience, patience and inference so it almost *looks* like you just plucked the answer out with supposed psychic powers ;-)

Comment: @CraigRinger - I am sorry for posting up an incomplete question but I really didn't slept for 3 days and my head was banging so i couldn't think of the proper procedure, I am sorry i will make sure it doesn't happen next time.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Thanks for such a deep explanation it didn't worked though here is the error:
ERROR:  column p.associateduserid does not exist
LINE 4:    SELECT p.associatedUserId, count(s.id) AS id_ct
and i'll update the schema

Comment: @KeshavNair: Well, if you could supply the table definition in your question I could tell for sure. I *guess* you may be using double-quoted CamelCase identifiers like "associatedUserId" (contrary to what you posted but by way of my recently diagnosed psychic powers).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - No i didn't used double-qoutes i am using as it is that you posted

Comment: @KeshavNair: I only reproduced what you provided. Now, the added table definition for `pool_worker` confirmed my diagnosis. Psychic indeed! Amended my answer according to the new information.